# Как реализовать сохранение файла С# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

"Сохранить как" нетрудно реализовать, а вот с обычным сохранением без диалогового окна непонятно.

```
private void сохранитьToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
    return;
  // получаем выбранный файл
  string filename = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
  // сохраняем текст в файл
  System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filename, richTextBox1.Text);
  MessageBox.Show("Файл сохранен");
}

private void открытьToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
    return;
  // получаем выбранный файл
  string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
  //читаем файл в строку
  string fileText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename);
  richTextBox1.Text = fileText;
  MessageBox.Show("Файл открыт");
}
private void сохранитьToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  
}
```

Comment: Сделайте `filename` полем формы. И по этому пути сохраняйте повторно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно запомнить имя сохраненного или загруженного ранее файла

```cs
private void сохранитьToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    SaveFile(true);
}

private void открытьToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
        return;
    savedFileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(savedFileName);
    MessageBox.Show("Файл открыт");
}

private void сохранитьToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFile(false);
}

private string savedFileName;

private void SaveFile(bool saveAs)
{
    if (saveAs || savedFileName == null)
    {
        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
            return;
        savedFileName = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
    }
    File.WriteAllText(savedFileName, richTextBox1.Text);
    MessageBox.Show("Файл сохранен");
}
```

Еще советую не использовать русские буквы в названиях переменных, классов и прочих контролов.